# Styling v-list-item when used as multi-level menu

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am building a Vue 3 app using Vuetify 3. I have a multi-level menu within a `v-navigation-drawer` using `v-item-group`, as recommended in the documentation.  But I seem to be unable to change the font size of the menu items within the menu.

The code looks something like this:

```html
<v-list
   density="compact"
   :opened="opened"
   @update:opened="opened = $event.slice(-1)>
   <v-list-group v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item.title" :value="item">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
         <v-list-item
          v-bind="props"
          :key="item.title"
          :title="item.title">
         </v-list-item>
      </template>
      <v-list-item
        v-for="subMenu in item.subMenuItems"
        :key="subMenu.menu"
        :title="subMenu.menu"
        class="smaller-font"
        @click="log(subMenu.route)">
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

I've tried everything I can think of to change font of the menu items, including adding a specific class ("smaller-font" in the above) with `!important`, updating the specific `v-list-...` class styles, etc., but when I look at the Styles panel in the browser developer tools, the `html` tag font font-size seems to the one that the browser is respecting.

If it helps, there is a working example of the menu on the [Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlVVFv0zAQ/ismGuomNQnTQEJhm4aEJvHAy+BtmbQ0vm5mjm3ZTkqp8t85O3abtGxM4i323X1335fvkttN8lmprGshKZJzC43ilYXLUhBy3qW8WsvW+pM/i6pjD5VlUqRUVyvQZMWofbwokw/v3pYJ6dJGUuB4HsJlEmoHNGZsPBJCQRhm15hby0ZVtS2TXbCQCgRQDA4P49hVqyjOuJ9CLsgRdCBsZjir4Tg9PdlVbcfYDpI+aNkqnHgpNWIwpE6YIA2I9is+G2RTPIEbz4UyyywHd9dVvIVwO6LnkaN8iGq4tAWSYl1lfYMNUVoqQ/q9ot1AHnESIQi0YMJx9MVjFYJOhyMepPj7F5Muz/PRDFNO+cQT/545CmraxTfU0mnqG4dz0HZaE1iElMy9g4OUyOKlpJpXxricpuIcNE4iJq7y7qnRHU+YxOXDcQRDK1gY2WXPMk6Gvwu0vfdu2pk9XMfNwePB6gw75hLjkk20xqOpNVOWGLABmjVKaks2RMOS9GSpZUNmuLozl470pTCWbLcBk45vrW5hTpYVN3B3sksK2zskuZxRbLsCEWMgsYnk/JsoyOyaacx2+s3mMeYdj0HfNl6OX31BApyH9L0Q6gY6BityA46fmc2JfyEYyHW4Iv0WblT3Ra4ElxUl14zDpI6GyKTyLjzFmwNK3wEloM9w8iI+R2qfyg/WgHkEmLKxu1vST6cZvx20JmrvP0kXl3FKF5IcMufbe79aRxuX0qNBONQW6L2H6J2RBusEG9k1B2JqNAb1NsrG+xHh3XNq2G+c86P6Rd4MXquE/bQDdUCIkMyTIZo2lcp+Ginw3+Fh8CPjA7jhRQQuE3SoO5fJo7XKFHleU4Fl+KNgnc4E2FyoJr/CtFy3wmmUUtlcnWVn2fuc4hqNrzMwTbrQcmVAI0iZBBV9G8uW61e0Cpm+w2loEe5wGxfG9TjAzrFhh6JpEBS0+7e9jtJe2ZjWXuiAWlC+R8E5E09mT+vaeJ3DQv0vZ4/mneg69vPED4qth4rk7g8iH5I1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title in the v-list-item has its own font-size declaration, overriding the one on v-list-item.

You can target it directly, using a [`:deep`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors) selector in scoped CSS:

```css
.smaller-font :deep(.v-list-item-title) {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

---

To adjust the height of the list items, you have to override the min-height on the main v-list-item div:

```css
.smaller-font.v-list-item {
  min-height: unset; /* or a length that suits you */
}
```

Note that you need to beat a selectivity of two classes (it depends on the configuration of the list-item, but initial rules look like `.v-list-item--density-compact.v-list-item--one-line`). Depending on whether you use scoped styles and the list-item configuration, you might have to check the element and add more classes.

Here it is in the [updated playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Many thanks Moritz - that does the trick, although you need to do the same trick on `.v-list-item__append` to make the up and down arrows the same size.

The challenge I now face is how to get the line spacing of the menu to something more sensible - it seems stuck at the line spacing needed for the default font - any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, you mean list-item height, right? Have a look at the updated answer, does that work for you?

Comment: Many thanks again @moritz-ringler - I had to add a `height` style but with that change, it's exactly what I was after.  Sadly can't paste into a comment but 
`.smaller-font.v-list-item { min-height: 8px; height: 18px; }`
did the trick :-).